# how to query to find say 'TODO' from all installed packages on a Debian system?

Tags: debian, package-management, debian-jessie

I am looking to find the TODO files which are documents written by upstream developers when they are making some software. Is there a way to query that ? I am on jessie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-S` (search) option to `dpkg` which will search through all installed packages for any files matching the name pattern(s) given.

```
$ dpkg -S TODO
libtotem0: /usr/share/doc/libtotem0/TODO
libedataserver1.2-13: /usr/share/doc/libedataserver1.2-13/TODO
libwmf0.2-7:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libwmf0.2-7/TODO
libedataserverui-3.0-1: /usr/share/doc/libedataserverui-3.0-1/TODO
texlive-latex-extra-doc: /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/cweb-latex/src/TODO.gz
...
$
```

If you *only* want files named *exactly* `TODO` then put `*/` before the name (dpkg -S normal behavior is to surround the provided value with asterisks, causing a full-string substring match; this is overridden when there is an asterisk at the beginning):

```
$ dpkg -S \*/TODO
```

You can pass multiple file name patterns if you want:

```
$ dpkg -S \*/TODO \*/CHANGELOG
```

Works (tested) on Wheezy, should work equally well on Jessie.

The man page describes `-S` as the (not very verbose):

```
-S, --search filename-search-pattern...
    Search for a filename from installed packages.
```